# Error compressing files in /var/www with to .7z with password protection

Tags: backup, archive, compression

I am making a website that I run with apache from `var/www`, I have stopped the apache server and closed `gvim`, but when I right click on `compress`, select `.7z` compression with password. I get an error:

```
    An error occurred while adding files to archive.
```

I can copy the files, so why can't I compress them like this? I can also compress the files when I move the files to my home folder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use the "Compress" option in nautilus, first run `sudo nautilus` in a terminal in order to use that script with root permissions, then navigate to the `/var/www` folder and try again.

If you are dropping a terminal command in order to achieve the compress task, make sure you use `sudo` before the command.

To pack (make a file):

```
sudo tar cvf filename.tar /var/www/*
```

To pack and compress:

```
tar czvf filename.tar.gz /var/www/*
```

These examples will pack (and compress) the /var/www folder contents in a file named "filename.tar" (or "filename.tar.gz"). You should read your compression program help in order to gather information about how to do this from the terminal.

Good luck!

Comment: It would be better to use `gksudo nautilus`. Or in Terminal `7z a -p /tmp/test.7z /var/www`.

Comment: I yet wonder why people is always having better ideas than mine and they simply don't dare to post their own answer... Is it funny to put reviews? I will probably join... Thank you anyway, I am sure that ganjan will also thank you.